# how to stop viewstate going stale?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have an ASP.NET web forms app which uses HTML5 "Offline Web Apps" technology to store pages in the browser cache for an extended period of time. In this case it's possible for a user to press a button on the form and do a postback when it's days or weeks since the form was fetched from the server (i.e. a long time interval between the GET and POST requests).

Sometimes, this postback fails with the classic "Validation of viewstate MAC failed". My question is in 2 parts:

1. What causes the viewstate to go stale? i.e. how can I replicate the problem on demand?
2. Is there anything I can do to make sure this never happens? bearing in mind that there is advice saying I should never disable viewstate MAC.

Comment: Time causes it to go stale. ViewState doesn't make sense in a disconnected environment. I suggest you don't use it.

Comment: Interesting... In all my searching, I haven't seen any reference to a timeout for viewstate. do you have any information to back this up?

Comment: It's not a timeout. The ViewState Mac includes a time factor, I believe. The purpose is to prevent exactly what you're trying to do. ViewState wasn't meant for that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to solve this by adding a machine key to your web.config file.

You can use an online tool to generate a machine key, eg. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/.

In the web.config it goes under configuration > system.web.

It won't help, though, if you make changes to your web form or form ListItem values, etc.

You may be best not using an ASP.NET form and instead submitting via AJAX or using an HTML form (but still using ASP.NET Web Forms).

**Updated**

One of the reasons ViewState can go "stale" is if the application pool recycles or stops/restarts. Default settings in IIS will result in your website shutting down if there are no requests within a certain amount of time then restarting again when a request comes in.

One way you can test is to (1) open a web form on your site (2) make a change to your web.config file and resave (3) submit the form. If you don't have a machine key you will get a viewstate error at this point.

Comment: Thanks, I was definitely wondering about this. Unfortunately without understanding what makes it go stale in the first place, it's difficult to test whether specifying an explicit key has fixed the problem.

Comment: Good point. I have updated my answer with common cause and how to test.

Comment: Hmm, in my test, just changing the web.config file didn't cause the viewstate to expire, but rebooting the server did. After putting the explicit machine key, the viewstate is fine even after a server reboot. Without official documentation, I guess we can't be 100% sure but from a pragmatic point of view I can say to the customer that this change will probably stop the problem happening in future.

Comment: For me, changing the web.config caused the viewstate to expire, but I already have a machine key set.